# XHTML won't validate && and < in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, xhtml-1.0-strict

Here's the snippet of code that won't validate:

```
if (user_age > 15 && user_age < 91)
```

It gets the following errors:

> XML Parsing Error: StartTag: invalid element name

and

> XML Parsing Error: xmlParseEntityRef: no name

The first error is thrown for the "less than" and the second one is thrown twice, once for each ampersand.

Replacing the above signs with `&` and `<` validates fine, but of course it completely ruins the function.

Comment: You could replace your expression by this one: `!(!(user_age > 15) || !(91 > user_age))`. But that’s just a workaround.

Comment: Adding the CDATA tags fixed the issue. Thanks very much.

Comment: PROBLEM IF Javascript was into a XML and XHTML is generated by XSLT: the CDATA  ">", "<" and "&" are converted.                         alert((2>1)? 'OK1': 'OK2'); // is converted!  Use <xsl:value-of select="cdataNode" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Or you can protect the script from the xml validation like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
    if (user_age > 15 && user_age < 91) {
        // do soemthing
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: protect from xml validation, that sounds like cheating in a test. Literal &<> must be inside CDATA in valid XML, without it, Firefox should refuse rendering the document if Firefox were conformant (but now the document is probably not served as `application/xhtml+xml` so it won't happen.)

Answer (score 8):

Move script to other file :)

It is standard (and good) habit to separate style (into `.css` file), data (`.html`) and of course scripts to `.js` file.

Comment: css should also be in it's own file

Answer (score 2):

All Javascript should be [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xmL/xml_cdata.asp) in XHTML:

```
<![CDATA[
if (user_age > 15 && user_age < 91)
]]>
```

Comment: Don't forget to comment it out as <![CDATA[]]> is an XML literal in JavaScript.

Comment: Internet Explorer seems to conflict with this. For example, errors out when there are &lt; symbols in Javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

put javascript in `<![CDATA[...]]>` section

Comment: As stated in a reply to Martin's answer: Don't forget to comment it out as <![CDATA[]]> is an XML literal in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you can try CDATA but some time it wont work, it depends on the setting of the server I guess. I am not a pro, but i tested, and I did not work, but if you put the javascript code in the .js file and then link this file somewhere in your body. it will definitely work. *PERSONALLY TESTED*.