# XHTML XSLT Javascript that contains HTML tags

Tags: javascript

I have an XSLT file that renders a portion of an XHTML page. When it is added I get a "character data not allowed" error. If I wrap it in CDATA then I get more errors. Can anyone help with this please?

```
<script language="javascript">

YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function (ev) {

//...

    var myPaginatorConfig = { 
            containers   : "pagination",
                    rowsPerPage  : 1,
                    template     : "<table><tr><td>{PreviousPageLink}</td>"   +"<td><xsl:value-of select="jsfunc:getSliderDiv()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>"+
                                   "<td>{NextPageLink}</td></tr></table><xsl:value-of select="jsfunc:getClearDiv()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>",
                    totalRecords : Math.ceil(numItems / numVisible),

            previousPageLinkLabel : "Earlier Events",
            nextPageLinkLabel : "Later Events",
            previousPageLinkClass : "nav_button",
            nextPageLinkClass : "nav_button nav_button_right"
    }
//...

});

</script>
```

Comment: This is a not clear XSLT question: where are the reduce input sample, the desired output, the complete stylesheet or relationship explanation?

Comment: Also, what is the current output of the XSLT stylesheet? And what part of the javascript you posted is relevant to the problem? I don't see anything there about running an XSLT processor or adding the results to the page.

Comment: See also comment at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513871/xhtml-wont-validate-and-in-a-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

```
"<table><tr><td>{PreviousPageLink}</td>"   +"<td><xsl:value-of select="jsfunc:getSliderDiv()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></td>"+
                                   "<td>{NextPageLink}</td></tr></table><xsl:value-of select="jsfunc:getClearDiv()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>"
```

Your not escaping things here. Unless "yes" is a variable you should be using single quotes to enclose them, or use backslashes to escape the double quotes.

```
"<table><tr><td>{PreviousPageLink}</td>"   +"<td><xsl:value-of select="jsfunc:getSliderDiv()" disable-output-escaping=\"yes\"/></td>"+
                                   "<td>{NextPageLink}</td></tr></table><xsl:value-of select="jsfunc:getClearDiv()" disable-output-escaping=\"yes\"/>"
```

Comment: I tried escaping that and it still  didn't work. Thanks fo rthe help btw

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
      <![CDATA[ <script language="javascript"> your code</script> ]]>
</xsl:text>
```

The disable-output-escaping="yes" will leave your tags untouched
that solved many issues for me