# Error in for loop in JS inside stylesheet file

Tags: javascript, html, xslt

I have an `XSL` file and there is `HTML` part of it which I am writing my `javascript` function inside it as

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" >
    function Toggle_tbody(obj)
    {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
        if( obj.innerText == 'Expand all' ) 
        {
            obj.innerText = 'Collapse all';
            d = 'inline';
        } 
        else 
        {
            obj.innerText = 'Expand all';
            d = 'none';
        }

        var length = body.length
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = length;
        }
    }
</script>
```

But I have an error while compiling an it says:

> XML Parsing error at line 164:
>             StartTag: invalid element name

I should mention that line 164 is the beginning of for loop.

Would anyone let me know where is the error because as I see there shouldn't be any.

Comment: Try to put your code in `<![CDATA[...]]>`.

Comment: @RohanKumar You mean instead of `<script> ..... </script>` ?

Comment: I mean like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513871/xhtml-wont-validate-and-in-a-javascript-function

Comment: @RohanKumar thanks a lot. It works fine!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @RohanKumar for the hint.

Then here I found that it should be as

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" >
    function Toggle_tbody(obj)
    {
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody");
        if( obj.innerText == 'Expand all' ) 
        {
            obj.innerText = 'Collapse all';
            d = 'inline';
        } 
        else 
        {
            obj.innerText = 'Expand all';
            d = 'none';
        }

        //<![CDATA[
        var length = body.length
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = length;
        }
        //]]>
    }
</script>
```